# Monitoring Eclipse-plugin heap size *programatically*

Tags: eclipse, plugins, size, heap-memory

I know we can monitor heap size *manually* by ,

```
"Show heap status" under Window -> Preferences -> General
```

So is there anyway to say automatically grab the highest memory used in my eclipse plug-in?
This would be convenient to me because my plug-in could run for a long time and monitoring manually is not feasible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have here a [Simple Heap Size Monitor](http://www.blognote-info.com/index.php?2007/06/14/602-simple-heap-size-monitor);

```
long total = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Launched in a thread and log the total and free memory in a file.

If you encapsulate that in an eclipse plugin you could launch a custom eclipse with this activated by default and recording what you need.

---

Another (more simple) technique would be to attach to your eclipse session a [JConsole](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jconsole-1564139.html) configured to log what it [monitors](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=678) into a file.

[image: Low Memory detection at www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/1564119.jpg]

[JVMStat](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmstat-142257.html) (espacially [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html)) can be a good solution too.